# How to display array on the browser with javascript

Tags: javascript

the code I have provided allows users to input their name and favorite color which then gets put into an array. When I go to the console I can see that it works and everything looks good but I want to have it be displayed in its array in the browser and in the console. I have tried a few different ways but they have all been unsuccessful. any chance someone could help me?? Here is my code

```js
const array = []

const addUser = () => {
  const person = {
    name: document.getElementById('name').value,
    color: document.getElementById('color').value,
  };

  array.push(person)
  document.forms[0].reset();

  sort = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  })

  console.log(sort)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="formBox">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>


  <div class="formBox">
    <label for="color">Favorite color</label>
    <input type="text" id="color" placeholder="Color" />
  </div>

  <div class="formBox">
    <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="addUser(this)">Click to Add</button>
  </div>
  <div id="msg">
    <pre></pre>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Code seems to work fine

Comment: You'll have to explain better what "in the browser" means. I don't see an attempt to do that. Please revise to clarify.

Comment: I think he wants the name and color on the viewport or basically appended on the screen.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not specific enough and no attempt has been made (that we can see).

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you were looking for ?

(I assumed that by saying "showing in the browser" you were takling about using that `<pre>` element which is unused in your code, but it's a little unclear in your question)

```js
const array = []

const addUser = () => {
  const person = {
    name: document.getElementById('name').value,
    color: document.getElementById('color').value,
  };

  array.push(person)
  document.forms[0].reset();

  sort = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  })
  
  document.querySelector("#msg>pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(sort);
  console.log(sort)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="formBox">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>


  <div class="formBox">
    <label for="color">Favorite color</label>
    <input type="text" id="color" placeholder="Color" />
  </div>

  <div class="formBox">
    <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="addUser(this)">Click to Add</button>
  </div>

</form>
<div id="msg">
  <pre></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: That won't put the array inside the  pre  element though - it will put it at the same level - need a 'first-child' or similar

Comment: Oups you're right I didn't notice.. I fixed my answer